# Show $T: \mathcal{P}_n \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_n$ defined by $T(p(x)) = p(x) + p'(x)$ is an isomorphism

Tags: solution-verification, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

> Show $T: \mathcal{P}_n \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_n$ defined by $T(p(x)) = p(x) + p'(x)$ is an isomorphism

Let $c_0 + c_1x+c_2x^2 + ... + c_nx^n \in \mathcal{P}_n$

Suppose
$T(c_0 + c_1x+c_2x^2 + ... + c_nx^n) = 0$

$\Longrightarrow(c_0 + c_1) + (c_1 + c_2)x + ... + (c_{n-1} + c_n)x^{n-1} + c_nx^n = 0$

$\Longrightarrow c_n = 0$

$\Longrightarrow c_1 = c_2 = ... = c_n = 0$

Thus $kerT = \{\mathbb{0}\}$

And so $T$ is injective.

It follows from injectivity and equal dimensions of domain and codomain, that $T$ must be surjective.

Therefore $T$ is an isomorphism.

Is the above proof valid?

Comment: Looks great! Well done

Comment: That's the easier part, but you should first prove that $T$ is a linear transformation.

Comment: Surely this is the hard part? It follows from linearity of the derivative of that $T$ is linear.

Comment: @AlfredYerger I meant linearity is the easier part, but the wording didn't come out quite right.

Comment: Careful: $T(c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+\cdots+c_nx^n) = (c_0+c_1)+(c_1+2c_2)x+\cdots+(c_{n-1}+nc_n)x^{n-1}+c_nx^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we already know that these maps are linear transformations, your proof is valid; here's another one in case you're interested. The inverse transformation is
$$
T^{-1}(q(x)) = q(x) - q'(x) + q''(x) - \cdots + (-1)^n q^{(n)}(x),
$$
as is easy to check once it's written down.